# css background images are not showing in chrome but working on vs live server

Tags: html, css

i tried to show the picture in chrome but is not showing. it is visible in vs live server but in chrome is not.

when i used / it works with vs live server but in other browsers the background is not working

can you please help to solve this problem

here is the code:

html:

```
     <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a class="getstarted scrollto" href="indexAR.html">العربيه</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="hero-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="150">
      <h1>Plan. Launch. Grow.</h1>
      <h2>We hope to create a world where our descendants can enjoy a sustainable future</h2>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->
```

css:

```
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("/assets/img/5secondhome_lon_ii_sca_8820.png") top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: If your assets folder isn't hosted that would be why it isn't working

Comment: how i can make it hosted?

Comment: Well, it depends entirely on your tech stack, which you posted nothing about. is this made with a framework, or is it vanilla js?

Comment: it is vanilla js

Comment: Yea so I'm assuming you aren't using anything like express to host this? If that's the case the only thing you can do is move assets into your public folder

Comment: i tried with absolute and  relative to show the background image in the other browsers but it did not work

Comment: Please see my last comment and respond accordingly, thanks

Comment: i did it , but still the problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is coming from the `<link>` element.

If you have `<link>` with a `src` attribute that begins with a `period .` before the `relative slash` like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

Try correcting this without the `period .`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`

Comment: i tried it is not working

Comment: `<link href="assets/css/style copy.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: yeah it works fine with the live server , the images shown and everything is fine but when i open the (index.html) by chrome or Firefox all the images works but the background image for the hero section is not show

Comment: you use #hero two times in html files,  of course is doesn't work becouse id is unique.

Comment: is not working, please see the message above to understand the issue

Comment: the behaviour is different when you open an html file directly in chrome (the url looks like file:///etc...)
and when this file is hosted on a web server, you have to use a local web server like express or apache etc... to avoid this confusion